# Converting fractions into hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, hex

Say you had a number (28.5) and you needed to convert it into hexadecimal.

28 would be 1C, and 29 would be 1D, but what would 28.5 be?

Could you even convert that?

I'm asking this because I'm making a converter in JavaScript jsyk.

Comment: 28.5 in base 10 is 1C.8 in base 16, so there is a translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `n.toString(16)`.  I tested it, and (at least on Safari) it handles fractions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
28.5.toString(16);
```

Which correctly yields `1c.8`

Comment: I made a typo at first but fixed it :)