# Javascript: Parsing Double

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting hexadecimal to float in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript)

I am trying to parse Hex Value which is actually a hex representation of c++ double value.
I tried lot of things to convert/parse to double in java script but failed.

Please help and share the way to do this.

Comment: Show us your code and some examples of your string inputs

Comment: string input is '0xc3f5285c8f1cc840' answer should be 12345.12.