# NodeJS - Convert hexadecimal to float

Tags: node.js, hex

That may sound like a weird struggle and actually easy to do, but I cannot find a working way to convert an hexidecimal in a string format into a float.

My exemple is for instance: `406ea716`

If I convert it using one of the following website, I get `3.728948`.

http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html
http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/

I tried every single piece of code I found on the internet, but it won't return the same result.

Does it exist a module in NodeJS to perform the same conversion? If not, what can I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting hexadecimal to float in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. try this.

Buffer('406ea716','hex').readFloatBE(0)

> 3.7289481163024902

Answer (score 0):

No need for a module:

```
var hex = '406ea716';
// transform the hexadecimal representation in a proper js hexadecimal representation by prepending `0x` to the string
// parseInt() - because your example was an integer.
var num = parseInt( '0x' + '406ea716');
console.log( num );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this returns an integer (1080993558), while if I try to convert this hexadecimal with the websites I listed, it clearly returs a float.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `parseInt`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
$ node
> parseInt('406ea716', 16)
1080993558
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this is not the same result that the 2 websites I listed return.