# Javascript hexadecimal number validation using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, hex

My function should return true if the hexa number is valid using regular expressions
note: hexadecimal numbers may contain a point(.) for decimals (example: 2E6.A3)

Hexadecimal:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F

I gave examples on my main()

```js
function returnHexaNumber(string) {
    var regExp = /^[-+]?[0-9A-Fa-f]+\.[0-9A-Fa-f]?$/
    return (isAString(string) && regExp.test(string))
}
function main() {
    alert("true : " + returnHexaNumber('2E6'))
    alert("true : " + returnHexaNumber('2E6.A3'))
    alert("false : " + returnHexaNumber('ZZZ'))
    alert("false : " + returnHexaNumber(''))
    alert("false : " + returnHexaNumber(0))
    alert("false : " + returnHexaNumber('10'))
}
```

Comment: What's the issue/problem/question? Also, your snippet doesn't do anything probably because you're not calling `main`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made `\.` optional with `\.?` and the second `[0-9A-Fa-f]` take multiple characters by adding `*`.

```
function returnHexaNumber(s) {
    var regExp = /^[-+]?[0-9A-Fa-f]+\.?[0-9A-Fa-f]*?$/;
    return (typeof s === 'string' && regExp.test(s));
}
function main() {
    console.log("true : " + returnHexaNumber('2E6'));
    console.log("true : " + returnHexaNumber('2E6.A3'));
    console.log("false : " + returnHexaNumber('ZZZ'));
    console.log("false : " + returnHexaNumber(''));
    console.log("false : " + returnHexaNumber(0));
    console.log("true : " + returnHexaNumber('10'));
}

main();
```

Shouldn't `'10'` return true? I switched the last test.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/veyusokowu/edit?js,console