# reading float values from binary file (in after effects script)

Tags: javascript, binary, floating-point, extendscript, after-effects

I have a binary file containing data recorded using a c program.
the data stored in files are float values.
Now I need  to retrieve the float numbers from binary file in after effects script.
This is my code:

```
var myFile = File.openDialog('select file');
myFile.open("r");
myFile.encoding = "binary";
for(x=0;x<myFile.length;x += 4){
     myFile.seek(x,0);
     buffer = myFile.read(4);
     ???
}
```

the question is how to convert the buffer to a float number.
Many Thanks in advance.

the input file is somthing like this :

7.26,-3.32,-5.18
7.66,3.65,-5.37
8.11,-4.17,5.11
8.40,-5.17,4.80

whitout any sepration character (,)

Each floating-point number uses 4 byte.

Comment: I'm guessing this is extendscript? Can you briefly explain what myFile.read(4) will set buffer to? Is it a string of 0s and 1s, or is it an actual binary number?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/message/101026#101026) will help you, but I can't find the official API documentation right now...

Comment: yes, it's extendscript.

Comment: And if you post the input file and write some desired output example, you'll get more help.

Comment: many thanks  Sangbok, I add some details to frist post

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It assumes the input was written by [IEEE 754 floating-point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). I used the parsing function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14090278/6153990). Sample input file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61520589/SO/extendscript/input.dat). It consists of 4 values(7.26, -3.32, -5.18, 7.66) without seperator, thereby its size is 4 * 4 = 16 bytes.

```
var myFile = File.openDialog('select file');
myFile.open("r");
myFile.encoding = "binary";

var buffers = [];
for(var x=0; x<myFile.length; x += 4) {
    myFile.seek(x, 0);
    var buffer = "0x";
    for(var y=0; y<4; y++) {
        var hex = myFile.readch().charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
        if(hex.length === 1) {
            hex = "0" + hex;
        }
        buffer += hex;
    }
    buffers.push(parseFloat2(buffer));

}
alert(buffers);


function parseFloat2(str) {
    // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14090278/6153990
    var float2 = 0;
    var sign, order, mantiss, exp, int2 = 0, multi = 1;
    if (/^0x/.exec(str)) {
        int2 = parseInt(str,16);
    } else {
        for (var i = str.length -1; i >=0; i -= 1) {
            if (str.charCodeAt(i)>255) {
                alert('Wrong string parametr'); 
                return false;
            }
            int2 += str.charCodeAt(i) * multi;
            multi *= 256;
        }
    }
    sign = (int2>>>31)?-1:1;
    exp = (int2 >>> 23 & 0xff) - 127;
    mantiss = ((int2 & 0x7fffff) + 0x800000).toString(2);
    for (i=0; i<mantiss.length; i+=1){
        float2 += parseInt(mantiss[i])? Math.pow(2,exp):0;
        exp--;
    }
    return float2*sign;
}
```

Comment: many many thanks Sangbok Lee!
your sample file has gone, and I can't test it. But as soon as possible I write a new sample file and I will test.

Comment: + can you reupload your sample file?

Comment: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bst2ssnzk804uga/input.dat?dl=0) it is.