# From hex to float - Javascript

Tags: javascript, lorawan

I am trying to convert a hex string to a float number in Javascript.

Suppose that I have the hex string "0082d241". Using [this online converter](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/) and selecting *Swap endianness*, the correct float value is 26,3135.

I know that this is the correct answer because it is from a TMP36 sensor.

I have tried some other examples that I found here on SO, such as [Converting hexadecimal to float in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript), but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to swap endianness, using the source code found on the [page](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/src/App.js) that you've shown.

Then you can convert the hexadecimal string to a float value.

```js
function flipHexString(hexValue, hexDigits) {
  var h = hexValue.substr(0, 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < hexDigits; ++i) {
    h += hexValue.substr(2 + (hexDigits - 1 - i) * 2, 2);
  }
  return h;
}


function hexToFloat(hex) {
  var s = hex >> 31 ? -1 : 1;
  var e = (hex >> 23) & 0xFF;
  return s * (hex & 0x7fffff | 0x800000) * 1.0 / Math.pow(2, 23) * Math.pow(2, (e - 127))
}

console.log(hexToFloat(flipHexString("0x0082d241", 8)));
console.log(hexToFloat(flipHexString("0x5d7e2842", 8)));
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, but this returns always the same value: 26.3134765625 whatever the measurment is. (i changed the "0x0082d241" in the last line of your code"

Comment: @kots There must be something wrong in your code. I've added a working code snippet to my answer to show you the results with two different hex strings

Comment: still have trouble. maybe because i use it with node red? here is how i use it:
ms = msg.payload.data;
function flipHexString(hexValue, hexDigits) {
  var h = hexValue.substr(0, 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < hexDigits; ++i) {
    h += hexValue.substr(2 + (hexDigits - 1 - i) * 2, 2);
  }
  return h;
}
function hexToFloat(hex) {
  var s = hex >> 31 ? -1 : 1;
  var e = (hex >> 23) & 0xFF;
  return s * (hex & 0x7fffff | 0x800000) * 1.0 / Math.pow(2, 23) * Math.pow(2, (e - 127));
}
msg.payload=hexToFloat(flipHexString(ms, 8));
  return msg;
@Teh

Comment: @kots Looks good to me, you should debug step by step what input you're getting in msg.payload.data and what is being returned, until you find what's wrong

Comment: the code now change the values but  they are in wrong format. It should be 26.2251 and it  is 5.45211154 e^-19 .