# Extract number form a hexadecimal dataFrame parseInt()ParseFloat()

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying to parse the data coming from some sensors, The data I recive is a hexadecimal number f.e.:
'450934644ad7a38441' I want to extract the last 8 characters, that are the value for temperature taken, and transform it into a readable number.
I tried this website: **https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/**

Here when you input d7a38441 it is processed and the wanted number is under Float - Little Endian (DCBA) system.
Also the conversion it`s doing is under UINT32 - Big Endian (ABCD) system

How do I convert this number into float? I Tried reading some other questions here but couldnt find a solution.
parseFloat() gives me NaN.

I would appreciate some light.

```js
var data = '450934644ad7a38441';

function main(data) {

  var result = [
    {      
        "key": "temperature",
        "value": parseInt('0x'+data.substring(10))
    }
    ]
  
  
  return result;
}

console.log(main(data));
// expected output: Array [Object { key: "temperature", value: 16.58 }]
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hex String to INT32 - Little Endian (DCBA Format) Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239567/hex-string-to-int32-little-endian-dcba-format-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I tried adapting this solutions already but im unable to make it works. Im new into javaScript so its harder for me to find a suitable answer for my problem

Comment: @MohamedRady yeah, I tried, using  parseInt(data.substring(10),16) is similar to:  parseInt('0x'+data.substring(10))

Comment: On a side note, if you want *the last 8 characters*, `data.substr(-8)` might be semantically better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442676/7690242) what you need. String received by function `yourStringToFloat` is your `data` variable received by main function in your example. Of course you can fix precision according to your needs.

```js
function flipHexString(hexValue, hexDigits) {
  var h = hexValue.substr(0, 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < hexDigits; ++i) {
    h += hexValue.substr(2 + (hexDigits - 1 - i) * 2, 2);
  }
  return h;
}


function hexToFloat(hex) {
  var s = hex >> 31 ? -1 : 1;
  var e = (hex >> 23) & 0xFF;
  return s * (hex & 0x7fffff | 0x800000) * 1.0 / Math.pow(2, 23) * Math.pow(2, (e - 127))
}

function yourStringToFloat(str){

    return hexToFloat(flipHexString("0x"+str.substr(10), 8))

}

console.log(yourStringToFloat('450934644ad7a38441'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Karol, I really appreciate! This helped me a lot