# Convert a number (also float) to a hexadecimal and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, floating-point, hex

I'm trying to create two functions: the first one that converts a number (also float) to a hexadecimal string and the second one that does the vice versa.

This is my code:

```js
function base10ToBase16(base10) {
  const precision = decimalsLength(base10)
  const multiplied = base10 * Math.pow(16, precision)
  const hexadecimal = multiplied.toString(16)
  
  if (isInteger(base10)) return hexadecimal
  return insertAt(hexadecimal, '.', hexadecimal.length - precision)
}

function base16ToBase10(base16) {
  const [integerPart, decimalPart] = base16.split('.')
  if (!decimalPart) return parseInt(integerPart, 16)
  return parseInt(integerPart, 16) + parseInt(decimalPart, 16) / Math.pow(16, decimalPart.length)
}

/////////////////////////
// Test
/////////////////////////
const numbers = [0, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 0.85, 0.855, 0.8555, 100, 255]
const hexes = numbers.map(n => base10ToBase16(n))
console.log(hexes)
console.log(hexes.map(h => base16ToBase10(h)))



/////////////////////////
// Utility functions
/////////////////////////
function insertAt(str, toAdd, position) {
  return `${str.slice(0, position)}${toAdd}${str.slice(position)}`
}

function isInteger(value) {
  return Number(value) === value && value % 1 === 0
}

function decimalsLength(value) {
  const [integerPart, decimalPart] = value.toString().split('.')
  return decimalPart ? decimalPart.length : 0
}
```

As you can see, `hexes` and `numbers` are not equals.
Is there a way to do that?
I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055723/converting-hexadecimal-to-float-in-javascript) and I tried to follow their suggestions.

Comment: It looks like your integers are working fine, and the problem is only with your floats.

Comment: @Dshiz do you mean that `base10ToBase16` seems to work? Do you have some tips to make works also `base16ToBase10`?

Comment: `base16ToBase10` is correctly converting the integers back into integers, but not the floats back into floats as you can see with `NaN` in one of the results and the others are incorrect when compared to the original numbers. Unfortunately, I don't have any ideas on how to correct it. I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: One of the issues is that, when the base ten number is less than zero, you get an empty string for the units part. For example, `0.5` converts to `'.8'`. When you try to convert that back to base 10, `parseInt('',16)` gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `base16ToBase10` is fine. Your `base10ToBase16` is wrong. Look at the snippet output.

```js
function insertAt(str, toAdd, position) {
  return `${str.slice(0, position)}${toAdd}${str.slice(position)}`
}

function isInteger(value) {
  return Number(value) === value && value % 1 === 0
}

function decimalsLength(value) {
  const [integerPart, decimalPart] = value.toString().split('.')
  return decimalPart ? decimalPart.length : 0
}
function base10ToBase16(base10) {
  const precision = decimalsLength(base10)
  const multiplied = base10 * Math.pow(16, precision)
  const hexadecimal = multiplied.toString(16)
  
  if (isInteger(base10)) return hexadecimal
  return insertAt(hexadecimal, '.', hexadecimal.length - precision)
}

function base16ToBase10(base16) {
  const [integerPart, decimalPart] = base16.split('.')
  if (!decimalPart) return parseInt(integerPart, 16)
  return parseInt(integerPart, 16) + parseInt(decimalPart, 16) / Math.pow(16, decimalPart.length)
}

const numbers = [0, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 0.85, 0.855, 0.8555, 100, 255]
const wrong_hexes = numbers.map(base10ToBase16)
const hexes = numbers.map(n => n.toString(16))
console.log(wrong_hexes + "")
console.log(hexes + "")
console.log("hexes NOT eq wrong_hexes = ", hexes + "" !== 
wrong_hexes + "")

const roundtrip_numbers = hexes.map(base16ToBase10)
console.log(numbers + "")
console.log(roundtrip_numbers + "")
console.log("roundtrip_numbers eq numbers = ", roundtrip_numbers + "" === numbers + "")
```

Not really sure what are you trying to achieve with your own `base10ToBase16` function. You already using `toString(16)` inside it. So the simplest way would be to use `numbers.map(n => n.toString(16))` instead.